# Can mongodb send query pipelining with no loop?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, join, transactions

I'm new to NodeJS and MongoDB.

I wanna get user's profile with one user's following list. If I use RDB, it was so simple with `EQ join` but I didn't have much experience of MongoDB, I don't know how.

Sample data below.

```
// list of users
[
  {
    _id: "oid_1",
    nickname: "user_01",
    link: "url/user_01"
  },
  {
    _id: "oid_2",
    nickname: "user_02",
    link: "url/user_02"
  },
  {
    _id: "oid_3",
    nickname: "user_03",
    link: "url/user_03"
  }
  ...
]
```

```
user_01's followList
[
  {
    followOid: "foid_1",
    userOid: "user_01"
  },
  {
    followOid: "foid_2",
    userOid: "user_02"
  },
]
```

My solution is, get follow list, then use loop with `follows.findOne()` like below

```js
const dataSet = [];
Follow.getFollowerList(userId) // for pipeline, use promise
    .exec()
    .then( async (result) => { // no async-await, no data output...
      for (let data of result) {
        let temp = await Users.getUserInfo( // send query for each data, I think it's not effective
          data.userId,
          { nickname: 1, link: 1 }
        );
        dataSet.push(temp);
      }
      return dataSet;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(200).json(data);
    })
    .catch( ... )
```

I think it's not best solution. If you are good at mongodb, plz save my life :)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use aggregation.

```
const userId = 'Fill with UserId';
const pipe = [
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': userId
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'followListCollectionName', 
      'localField': '_id', 
      'foreignField': 'userOid', 
      'as': 'followList'
    }
  }
];
const result = await UserModel.aggregate(pipeline);
```

and then you can find an array in result  which contains one user with given Id ( and more if there are with same Id) and `result[0].followList` you can find follow objects as array

Second Option is to use virtuals

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html

but for this schema of your collection needs some changes.

Good luck